# OctoberCMS - onepage site with meta data generation

Tags: laravel, backbone.js, metadata, octobercms

I have one page website using backbone js and its router.

I want to use middlewere (or htaccess) to work with categories and subcategories and id's to generate meta data for google indexing.

simply i need to use http://host/path/id but let october to load index page.

I know that it's not the smartest way, but site already finished.

I'm trying to use middlewere to catch the path and redirect to home page using data

Comment: Since its a spa you will have issues anyway with seo without using server side rendering or prerender.io I know this isn't an answer but something to consider

Comment: i dont think you right. follow my idea: once i'm getting into middlewere, i can generate data and render view with metadata. thats it. or i'm missing it globally. 
still thanks for a comment, ill chekc prerender

Comment: https://github.com/JeroenNoten/laravel-prerender
here middlewere for laravel. 
interesting

Comment: you can create `index/home page` with url `/:params` so every thing will be handled by index page and your `js router` can parse parameters i guess

Comment: Interesting idea. thanks ill try